# Quantization processs

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, digital-communications, signal-synthesis

In a quantization process what happens when the signal range is more than the quantizer range?

Suppose i have a sinusoidal signal which ranges from -5 to +5 but the quantizer which has four levels ranges from -3 to 3.now for the samples which are greater than 3 and less than -3 what will happen?

Answer (score 1):

In a typical quantization like that seen in an ADC the output would saturate any value > 3 to 3 (also known as clipping). Note that if you're considering a software quantization, it's also possible that some quantizers (although IMO poorly designed ones) could cause out of range values to wrap around and switch signs.

Answer (score 1):

A "quantization process" is a mathematical abstraction.

Things like analog to digital converters, conversions from wider databusses to narrower databusses, etc., are actual physical processes.

A purely mathematical process that quantizes in steps of 2 (i.e., $\left \lbrace \cdots, -3, -1, 1, \cdots \right \rbrace$ would just keep quantizing, because its effects would extend to infinity in both directions.

When you model some *real thing* that quantizes, you need to model the behavior of that real thing.

In general, an ADC will, when you put a voltage on it that's a bit outside of its range, return a number at its extreme -- i.e. a 12-bit ADC might return h'fff or h'000.  But if you put a voltage on an ADC that's a *lot* outside its range (usually more than one diode drop), then all sorts of weird chip-specific bad things happen.  They don't latch up and get hot any more (that I know of), but about 20 years ago I worked with an 8-channel ADC that would, if any one channel exceeded the design voltage, get erroneous readings on *all eight* channels.

OTOH, a stage that narrows a datapath by lopping off bits from the least-significant end will just increase quantization, while a stage that narrows a datapath by truncating bits from the most-significant end may wrap (i.e., h'80000 may become h'0000, for a really big difference in apparent magnitude).

So its generally best to find out or figure out what the hardware actually does when signals exceed their design limits, and model that.